# Apache Directory directive not working behind a elastic load balancer

Tags: apache-httpd

I am using directory listing from specific IP ranges. Recently, we moved the web server to AWS and using ELB. Now, even I am in IP range the Apache say's forbidden access. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any proxy or ELB between Client and WebServer the visible IP to WebServer will be that proxy/ELB IP. In that scenario you can limit access through `X-Forwarded-For` IP.

Here are some example:

Apache 2.4

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "202.12.32.1" allowed_list
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "202.32.32." allowed_list 
Require env allowed_list
```

Apache 2.2

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "202.12.32.1" allowed_list
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "202.32.32." allowed_list
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allowed_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable and configure [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html).  You will need to identify the IP addresses used by ELB.  (Or you could allow anyone to spoof X-Forwarded-For, but use some firewall facility to block accesses to your webserver which do not come from the ELBs.  Maybe Amazon has such a feature).

Comment: Through AWS security group he can allow/block traffic. His requirement is something different. He has `DirectoryIndex` enabled for a specific Directory and he want to limit access to that directory.

Comment: @SouravMaity great!  mod_remoteip will allow vishnupanati to achieve their aim based on the X-Forwarded-For header set by the ELB.  But, if vishnupanati allows mod_remoteip to work for connections which didn't go through the ELB, then anyone can bypass the protection by sending an X-Forwarded-For which specifies one of the allowed IPs.

Comment: @SouravMaity this will allow to continue using the native IP-matching features.  This should be clearer if you have to match IPv6, for example.